# DstNat changes address but recipient does not respond

Tags: networking, nat

i have 2 local networks in [this configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt3dD.png) and i'm trying to let x.x.1.37 comunicate with x.x.100.11; i have setup on router 2 DstNAT so that the packets sent to x.x.1.42 are forwarded to x.x.100.11 and a SrcNAT so that the packets sent by x.x.100.11 look like they have been sent by x.x.1.42 but whenever i try to ping x.x.x.1.42 from x.x.1.37 i get no response. i can see the dstNat rule does infact change the destination address but x.x.100.11 does not appear to send a response.
Sorry for the rambly mess i have been on this for two days and i'm loosing my mind
( router 1 is an isp issue router, router 2 is a mikrotik rb750gr3)
router 1 is plugged into router 2's wan port (ether 1).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please edit in the actual IP addresses+mask, as it looks like there are some typos. If you are using the wan port, then Router2 should have two IPs (internal and external/wan). Is Router1 connected to the internet? Router1 will need a route to send `x.x.100.x` packets through Router2